# Identify this music in a wedding video

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I tried all the ways to find what is this music in a [zainabfilms](https://www.instagram.com/p/BoM900DFFlC/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=bt42315ud5s1) wedding video, I asked the owner of the post but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is ["Aeon" by Nick Murray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6vwmrEtkd0).

It has also been used as trailer music in Disney's 2015 movie [Cinderella](https://youtu.be/20DF6U1HcGQ?t=60).